# Laravel 5.4, reusing a if else statement throughout site

Tags: php, laravel-5

I found myself needing to repeat the if else statement throughout the site because I have two url's. One is for admin, one is for users. Do I have to separate out the controllers to stop this or is there a better way to do this?

URL structure :
**Admin :** /buildings/{building_id}/tenants
**Users :** /tenants

**TenantsController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request, $building_id = null)
{

   if($request->user()->hasRole('admin')){
        $building_id = $building_id;
   }else{
        $building_id = Auth::user()->building_id;
   }

   $building = Building::findOrFail($building_id);

   $tenants = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){$q->whereIn('name', ['tenant']);})->where('building_id',$building_id)->paginate(2);

   return view('buildings.tenants.index')->withTenants($tenants)->withBuilding($building);
}
```

Comment: If you want to filter out something at the top , use middleware

Answer (score 1):

Use middleware, Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the application. if you want more info about middleware check this page [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware)